# Text in TextView gravity not working

Tags: android, textview

I written the following function to create text view.But some the text not visible completely so i get gravity to center_horizontal|center|vertical but it is not working.I the following images IN DATE & OUT DATE not visible completely.So i want to set all text to center vertical and center horizontal

```
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        //textView.setPadding(0,0,0,25);

        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    [![enter image description here][1]][1]    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding + 10);

        return textView;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show your layout xml? May be another view overlaps this text view

Comment: Cant we move the text little bit up

Comment: Your TextView dimensions seem to be fixed and it is not tall enough to display the whole text. You may consider setting the top and bottom padding to zero in all TextView cells.

Answer (score 2):

Your `TextView's` height is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`, so it's internal `Gravity` has no effect on it's vertical positioning (because there's no extra bounds to position itself in).

If you want to get it vertically aligned, you need to either set the `TextView's` PARENT gravity to `CENTER_VERTICAL`, or set the TextView's height to `MATCH_PARENT`.

Either of those will give you the effect you seek.